# Integrating smart pointers with legacy code raw pointers

Tags: pointers, unique-ptr

I have a situation, where I have existing code that works with raw pointers, and I'm not permitted to smart-pointer-ify it. However, I am permitted to use smart pointers in any new code I develop.

For example.

I have an existing function like:

```
void processContent()
{
    ContentObject * myContent = new ContentObject();
    newFunction(myContent);
}

void newFunction(ContentObject * content)
{
    // myVector is just a std::vector<ContentObject*>, defined elsewhere
    myVector.push_back(content);
}

void doSomethingWithContent()
{
    // There is some logic here, but ultimately based on this logic I want to remove entries, and free the memory they point to.
    myVector.pop_back();
}
```

I have control over the content of "newFunction" and "doSomethingWithContent". But the argument passed into newFunction is fixed. Obviously I could manually delete the pointer in myVetor, before popping it, but I wondered if I can implement smart pointers here so that it happens "automatically" for me?

Can I take a raw pointer passed into a function, and turn it into a unique_ptr, then add this to a container, and have it delete the memory when it's popped from the container?

Thanks

Joey

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you can define your myVector as the following:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ContentObject>> myVector;
```

In that case you can switch on smart pointers in your code and myVector will keep all your objects as you expected:

```
void newFunction(ContentObject * content)
{
   myVector.push_back(std::shared_ptr<ContentObject>(content));
}

void doSomethingWithContent()
{
  // There is some logic here, but ultimately based on this logic I want to       remove entries, and free the memory they point to.
  myVector.pop_back();
}
```